# What is the best way to build a dictation topic for windows speech recognition?

Tags: speech-recognition, sapi

I want to build a language model for a big list of words in order to create another topic in the dictation topic of windows speech recognition. Please tell me what will be the best way for that.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the [Dictation Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23262) to build custom language models.  It's not very user-friendly, though; it's built for speech scientists by speech scientists.

That being said, however, there *is* an example of how to use it [here](http://mperfect.net/dicResKit/).  It also describes how to register your freshly built LM so that Windows Speech Recognition can use it.